# Checking the value of a tag in an AWS IAM policy, when that tag has multiple (delimited) values

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I'm intending to set up something similar to attribute-based access control, using an approach similar to the one outlined [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-ec2-resource-tags/) by Amazon. For example, I'll have resources with `environment` tags, with values like `prod`, `preprod`, and `test`. Access control policies that use these values will be defined in CloudFormation templates.

Resources should be able to have multiple values for a tag - e.g. `environment=test:preprod`. How would I represent this requirement in a policy? Would I need to write something unwieldy like...

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
      ...
    "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {"ec2:ResourceTag/environment": [
            "*:prod:*",
            "prod:*",
            "*:prod",
            "prod"
        ],
        "StringNotLike": {"ec2:ResourceTag/environment": [
            "preprod:*"
        ]
   }}
}
```

...for the policy document if I wanted to distinguish between `prod` and `preprod`, while also allowing `prod` to be anywhere in the list of tag values?

Comment: I suggest you to store tags like: `isProd`, `isDev`

Comment: I too would like an answer to using a compound/mutl-value tag in a ABAC policy model